# How can I get IntelliJ IDEA's "Show in Files" to open Nemo instead of Nautilus?

Tags: 14.10, filemanager, default, intellij

In IntelliJ IDEA (or any of its related IDEs such as PyCharm, WebStorm, etc) you can right click a file or folder and select `Show in Files` as highlighted here

[image]

When I do this, it opens the folder in Nautilus.  I would like to open this in Nemo.

I have already run this command

```
xdg-mime default nemo.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search
```

to set Nemo as default, however IntelliJ does not seem to recognize it.  What can I do to make IntelliJ open these paths in Nemo and not Nautilus?

(Ubuntu 14.10)

Comment: I asked on [the Jetbrains forums](https://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/461725) and had to reinstall Nemo, so couldn't figure out what the problem was.

Comment: I have it set to `Show in Dolphin` and am trying to revert it to `Show in Files` to use Nautilus